# can i start a selenium server with different port

Tags: selenium

can i start a selenium server with different port from my code like we do

seleniumserver s= new seleniumserver();
s.start()

and set port??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RemoteControlConfiguration conf = new RemoteControlConfiguration();
conf.setPort(1234);
SeleniumServer ss = new SeleniumServer(false, conf);
```

Comment: i think you didnt understand my question clearer ,my question is to start my selenium server in other port (not in 4444).that too from code.
i know we can start selenium server from code (as i said above),but how to set port??

Answer (score 3):

Actually there's a constructor that accept a port number

```
SeleniumServer server = new SeleniumServer(1234);
server.start();
```